# web3 providers for ethereum apart from metamask, to connect web and mobile dapps?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, web3-providers

I want to create a list of ethereum web3 providers available apart from metamask, which could be used to integrate blockchain functionalities in our apps or dapps created in various platforms (web app, mobile web app, iOS, Android, even desktop apps). Could you please specify all that you know. Would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal, it has many providers that you can check out. Also, for easy onboarding web2 users into your dApp you should check [Abridged](https://www.abridged.io/) or [Unilogin](https://unilogin.io/)